# Error: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection when Trying to Get Picture From Camera Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

at this time i want to ask about my code below, it's supposed simple code for capturing picture / photo from camera in Android, but the code isn't working, This my code below..

```
 package com.example.category.search;
 import com.example.search.R;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class CreateData_Camera extends Activity {
 private Button btCamera;
 private ImageView ivCamera;
 private static final String TAG = CreateData_Camera.class.getSimpleName();
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 7777;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
      btCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_camera);
      ivCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_camera);

      btCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            //After taking picture with camera, the code below isn't working, the
            //intent is not delivered to the code below, 
            //Then I got Warning in my logcat : it say's
            //showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection when Trying to Get Picture From Camera Android 

            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
 }

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case(CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) :
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ivCamera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

this is my logcat:

```
  04-29 12:00:23.040: D/dalvikvm(27599): GC_EXPLICIT freed 181K, 52% free 6927K/14308K,        paused 2ms+4ms, total 25ms
  04-29 12:00:35.233: I/Adreno200-EGL(27599): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4       QUALCOMM build:       AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.04.02.02.040.400_msm8960_JB_2.5_CL3744273_release_AU (CL3744273)
  04-29 12:00:35.233: I/Adreno200-EGL(27599): Build Date: 06/30/13 Sun
  04-29 12:00:35.233: I/Adreno200-EGL(27599): Local Branch: 
  04-29 12:00:35.233: I/Adreno200-EGL(27599): Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5
  04-29 12:00:35.233: I/Adreno200-EGL(27599): Local Patches: NONE
  04-29 12:00:35.233: I/Adreno200-EGL(27599): Reconstruct Branch:       AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.04.02.02.040.400 +  NOTHING
  04-29 12:00:43.662: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27599): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

can anyone help me about this issue? I really confuse with this warning, i really need help about this case. Thank you